# What is the solution to the problem of other minds?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, argumentation, explanation

Can you explain which solution to the problem of other minds is the best.

As I understand it, the best explanation argument is the best solution to the problem of other minds.

It is written here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#BestExpl

But here they say that this argument is not good. [What argument in favor of other minds is relevant now?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94035/what-argument-in-favor-of-other-minds-is-relevant-now?noredirect=1#comment268566_94035)

An argument by analogy is also considered not very good: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal

It is also noted that a true solution to the problem of other minds must contain several arguments.

As far as I know there are only two good arguments in favor of other minds:

This is the argument of the best explanation and the argument by analogy.

But these arguments are not good as far as I understand.

It turns out that there are no good arguments in favor of the existence of other minds? That is, the arguments against are more convincing?

I have a question:

1. What are the best and most convincing arguments for the existence of other minds?
2. What solution to the problem of other minds is the best (is it some argument or several arguments)?
3. Are the arguments against other minds more persuasive?

thank you

Comment: You could walk up to someone, tell them they don't have a mind, and see what they do. Philosophy is an experimental science. (But also a non-contact sport.) Did you expect this response?

Comment: What are the best and most convincing arguments for the existence of other minds?

Comment: What solution to the problem of other minds is the best (is it some argument or several arguments)?

Comment: I am sadly unprepared to give an academic answer, but as a person with a basically Engineering and practical mindset, I usually propose to people that they just try things and find good answers themselves before comparing to the historical and academic ones. If this was a conversation, I would gladly talk with you about what you have tried and seen. You might be able to find a group to discuss in. I run a Meetup group like that. It works well. Start one, if you can't find one.

Comment: Voting to close in favor of one of the other identical questions by this poster.